# SQL Computed Column: Using an conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a pretty basic SQL question. I have two tables (Table A and Table B) in play here and I am trying to make a computed column in one of them. Let's say it's a column in Table A.

The computed column needs to come from the "TotalTime" corresponding column value in Table A minus the "DelayTime" column values in Table B where the ID column of Table B matches the current ID value of Table A. I guess in a mathematical format, it would look like this:

```
BuildTime = TotalTime - SUM(DelayTime) WHERE [TableB].ID = [TableA].ID
```

I just don't know the correct format to do this.

Comment: You cannot construct a computed column using data outside the "current" row of the table you where the column is defined (well, you can using a UDF).  I would recommend a view to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your intent, it sounds like you may want to query something like this:

```
SELECT totaltime - SUM(delaytime)
FROM TABLE A 
JOIN TABLE B ON A.id = B.id
```